# Accessing Airflow REST API in AWS Managed Workflows?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa, airflow-api

I have Airflow running in AWS MWAA, I would like to access REST API and there are 2 ways to do this but doesn't seem to work for me.

1. Overriding api.auth_backend.  This used to work and now AWS MWAA won't allow you to add this, it is consider as 'blocklist' and not allow.
   api.auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.default
2. Using MWAA Cli(Python).  This doesn't work if any of the DAGs uses packages that are in requirments.txt file.
   a. as an example, I have "paramiko" in requirements.txt because I have a task that uses SSHOperator.  The MWAA Cli fails with "no module paramiko"

   b. Also noted here, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/access-airflow-ui.html
   "Any command that parses a DAG (such as list_dags, backfill) will fail if the DAG uses plugins that depend on packages that are installed through requirements.txt."

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @ypicard Unfortunately no,  they did however released Airflow 2.x as part of MWAA.  I'm going to test that version.

Comment: I am running the Airflow v2.x in MWAA and the API is not available at the moment in this version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67884770/is-it-possible-to-access-the-airflow-api-in-aws-mwaa?noredirect=1#comment119989884_67884770

Comment: @ypicard That's unfortunate.

Answer (score 2):

We are using MWAA 2.0.2 and managed to use Airflow's Rest-API through MWAA CLI, basically following the instructions and sample codes of the [Apache Airflow CLI command reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/airflow-cli-command-reference.html). You'll notice that not all Rest-API calls are supported, but many of them are (even when you have a requirements.txt in place).

Also have a look at [AWS sample codes on GitHub](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-mwaa-examples/tree/main/dags/bash_operator_script).